# Android - TableRow is not being added to a TableLayout in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablelayout, tablerow

I had an activity with a TableLayout in it and now I'm changing the part with the table into a fragment. I'm trying to dynamically add rows to a `TableLayout` from inside that fragment. I got a layout for the `TableRow` which I add and I try to inflate it, set the data and add it to the table.

When I'm doing it in an `activity` it works. Now when I moved the part of the table to a `fragment`, it doesn't work and the part where the table is supposed to be, remains blank like there's nothing there.

The code that works in the activity:

```
    private void AddNewRowToTable(String string1, String string2)
    {
        // Inflate your row "template" and fill out the fields.
        TableRow row = (TableRow)LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.table_row, null);
        ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textViewName1)).setText(string1);
        ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textViewName2)).setText(string2);
        row.setOnClickListener(_rowOnClickListener);
        table.addView(row);
    }
```

and the table var was defined:

`table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayoutWorkers);`

And this is the code that does NOT work in the fragment:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        this.containingActivity = getActivity();
        this.inflater = inflater;
        currentFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_show_statistics, null);
        table = (TableLayout)currentFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.tableLayoutWorkers);        
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_show_statistics, container, false);
    }
```

and a small change in the method:

```
private void AddNewRowToTable(String string1, String string2)
    {
        // Inflate your row "template" and fill out the fields.
        TableRow row = (TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row, null);
        //all the rest is the same
    }
```

Since I'm new to this, I'm not sure when should I use a `View`, and when should I use a `Context` or a `ViewGroup` and why.

Do you know why does the table not get filled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your oncreateView method you inflate two fragment_show_statistics you return one, the other you find the table in.

So you need to return the one that you find the table from.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    this.containingActivity = getActivity();
    this.inflater = inflater;
    currentFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_show_statistics, null);
    table = (TableLayout)currentFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.tableLayoutWorkers);        
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return currentFragmentView;
}
```

Comment: I'm not near the computer I wrote the code so I can check it tomorrow. Is it possible that you also edit your answer and explain the difference between Context and View and GroupView? Since I'm not sure when to use one or the other.